# Eclipse Plug-in Installation Error

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I get the following error while trying to install PMD, Find Bugs, Lint4j etc. Any idea?

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
  No repository found containing: org.aspectj.ajde/osgi.bundle/1.6.4.20090106083800
  No repository found containing: org.aspectj.runtime/osgi.bundle/1.6.4.20090106083800
  No repository found containing: org.aspectj.weaver/osgi.bundle/1.6.4.20090106083800
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.ajdt.core/osgi.bundle/1.6.3.20090122141228
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.ajdt.doc.user/osgi.bundle/1.6.3.20090122141228
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.ajdt.examples/osgi.bundle/1.6.3.20090122141228
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.ajdt/org.eclipse.update.feature/1.6.3.20090122141228
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.ajdt.source/osgi.bundle/1.6.3.20090122141228
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.ajdt.source/org.eclipse.update.feature/1.6.3.20090122141228
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.ajdt.ui/osgi.bundle/1.6.3.20090122141228
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.aspectj/osgi.bundle/1.6.3.20090122141228
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.contribution.visualiser/osgi.bundle/2.2.0.20090122141228
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.contribution.xref.core/osgi.bundle/1.6.3.20090122141228
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.contribution.xref.ui/osgi.bundle/1.6.3.20090122141228
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.ajdt.mylyn.ui/osgi.bundle/1.6.3.20090122141228
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt/osgi.bundle/1.6.3.20090122141228
```

Comment: I was using a repository for a different eclipse release. They are codenamed. I thought the funny name was some central software project's name, but no, it was the codename of a eclipse version, and I have the wrong one selected. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the version of your eclipse?

There is a bug regarding updates: **[236437](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=236437)** only fixed in 3.5M4

If that happens, the current workaround is to remove the repository from the list and add it back again.

- `Software Updates -> Manage sites -> Export (bookmarks.xml)`
- exit eclipse
- go to your eclipse/`configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.*.prefs` and delete files (after backup)
- Restart eclipse
- re-import `bookmarks.xml`

Comment: Glad this workaround worked for you. I guess you were not using eclipse3.5 Galileo, then?